# use variables for defining width and height

Tags: javascript, html

```
var w=300;
var h=300;

function openWin()
{
w=window.open("http://www.google.com","mywin","width=w, height=h,screenX=50,left=50,screenY=50,top=50,status=no,menubar=no");
}

<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="openWin()" />
```

---

Hi all,

I would like to know to use my own variables (var w and h)in defining opened windows.
No matter what combination I try, the width and height attributes just don't work.

Thanks!

Comment: You have not properly closed the quotes and variable assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the variable, not just throw the letter in. Like this:

```
var w=300; var h=300;

function openWin()
{ 
 w=window.open("http://www.google.com","mywin","width=" + w + ", height=" + h + ", screenX=50,left=50,screenY=50,top=50,status=no,menubar=no"); 
}
```